# Mongoose not responding with data from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some code which uses some data from the **database: Assignment** and the **Collection: todolist**, which is supposed to interact with MongoDB and to add, delete or list the JSON in the collection.

To understand the problem I have to show the code before I explain it.

Here is the code for the model:

```js
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TaskSchema = new Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  desc: {
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);
```

Here is the code for the controller:

```js
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),

Task = mongoose.model('Task');

exports.list_all_tasks = function(req, res) {

  console.log("listing should commence");

  Task.find({}, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
      return;
    res.json(task);
  });

};

exports.create_a_task = function(req, res) {

  var new_task = new Task(req.body);
  new_task.save(function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
      return;
    res.json(task);
  });

};

exports.delete_a_task = function(req, res) {

  Task.deleteOne({
    _id: req.params.taskId
  }, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
      return;
    res.json({n: task.n, ok: task.ok});

  });

};
```

Here is the code for the route:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
  var todoList = require('./controller');

  // todoList Routes
  app.route('/tasks')

    .get(todoList.list_all_tasks)
    
    .post(todoList.create_a_task);

  app.route('/tasks/:taskId')

    .delete(todoList.delete_a_task);

};
```

Server.js file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
Task = require('./api/model'); //created model loading here
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const controller = require('./api/controller');

// mongoose instance connection url connection

//P.S The username and password have been taken off this security and privacy reasons
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://userName:password@server-4tjvi.mongodb.net/Assignment?retryWrites=true', { useNewUrlParser: true });

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var routes = require('./api/routes'); //importing route
routes(app); //register the route


app.listen(port);

console.log('Welcome to Just Do It, your Node.js application for all your To Do List needs.');
console.log('todo list API server has started on: port ' + port);
```

Ok so the problem that I have is that when I type in localhost:3000/tasks into Postman, it says it is loading for a long time and then it says it could not get a response. What I want it to do is to list all the tasks (JSON) from the collection onto postman.

I have set up MongoDB, I have downloaded everything that is required as well; mongoose, nodemon, Mongodb, etc.

And how do I upload things from my node application to the database collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is with `syntax`. Consider the following code (out of the several)

```
Task.find({}, function(err, task) {
  if (err)
    res.send(err);
    return;
  res.json(task);
});
```

In this block of code your `Task.find` is going to return `undefined` and `res.json` is never reached. And since your server does not send any response, the request is just going to time-out.

Just because return is *indented* doesn't mean it's part of `if` block. To make it a part of `if` block you've to put it in `braces {}`

Here's an illustration:

```js
function test() {
  let out;
  if (true)
    out === 'yes';
    return; // <-- not part of if block
  console.log('never reached')
  return out; // <-- never reached
}

console.log(test())
```

The above is equivalent to:

```js
function test(x) {
  let out;
  if (true)
    out === 'yes';
  return; // return undefined
}

console.log(test())
```

So refactoring it:

```
Task.find({}, function(err, task) {
  if (err) {
    res.send(err);
    return;
  }
  res.json(task);
});
```

Or `return` `res.send`

```
Task.find({}, function(err, task) {
  if (err)
    return res.send(err);
  res.json(task);
});
```